# Sampling of a pandas dataframe with groupby on one column such that the sample has no duplicates in another column

Tags: python, pandas, sampling

Assume the below dummy dataframe:

```
       a  b
0    red  0
1    red  1
2    red  3
3   blue  0
4   blue  1
5   blue  3
6  black  4
7  black  2
```

I want to sample on column a, with a sample size of 1. But the only condition is that in the sample created the values of column b should be unique, such that it gives me a result something like:

```
       a  b
2    red  0
3   blue  1
5  black  4
```

The below result is not acceptable:

```
       a  b
2    red  1
3   blue  1
5  black  4
```

Right now I am using below code with pandas sample function, but it is returning duplicate values in column b

```
df.groupby('a').sample(n=1)
```

Comment: This is potentially computationally hard. Imagine `df = pd.DataFrame(product(['red', 'blue', 'black'], [0,1,2]), columns=list('ab'))`.

Comment: I _suspect_ this is NP-hard, although I don't have a proof.

Comment: Yes, in my actual dataframe I have 9470 groups and 58178277 rows to sample from. I have tried sampling multiple times, but cannot find a logical way to code to choose uniques from those multiple samples

Comment: Perhaps ask the question on [Math Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: You can simplify your example and illustrate why it is hard: `r1, b1, g1, b2, g2, r3`. Greedily choosing `1` for `r`, for example, would cut off the only solutions (the ones where `b` and `g` need to share `1` and `2` between themselves).

Comment: @sahira95 - What are the value range and type of the actual column b?

Answer (score 0):

`sample(n=1)` selects values randomly from each element in column 'a'.

You can use `df.groupby('a').first()` which chooses the first value of each element, and would return the output you are looking for.

Comment: But the first values for many groups can still create duplicates in column 'b'. In my actual dataframe I have 9470 groups and 58178277 rows to sample from

Comment: Can you share an example? As it only selects the first value of each group there are no duplicates in column 'b'.